# Android Studio unable to render custom view in layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

I am creating a CustomView which basically wraps `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`. The Layout Editor in Android Studio is unable to show the preview of this custom view. I have tried Building the project, cleaned it and all, it still won't show the preview. Here is the Kotlin file for the same.

```
class PrimaryEditText : LinearLayout {
    private var textInputLayout: TextInputLayout
    private var textInputEditText: TextInputEditText
    private var onTextChangeListener: ((String) -> Unit)? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context, attrs, 0)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_edit_text, this)
        textInputLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout)
        textInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText)

        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PrimaryEditText)
        initAttrs(typedArray)
        typedArray.recycle()

        // Add TextWatcher to listen to text
        textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                onTextChangeListener?.invoke(s?.toString() ?: "")
            }
        })
    }

    /*
    * Initialize the attributes
    * */
    private fun initAttrs(typedArray: TypedArray) {
        val inputType = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.PrimaryEditText_android_inputType, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
        textInputEditText.inputType = inputType

        textInputLayout.hint = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.PrimaryEditText_hint)
    }

    /**
     * Set and get the text entered by the user
     * */
    var inputText: String
        get() = textInputEditText.text.toString()
        set(value) {
            textInputEditText.setText(value)
        }

    /**
     * Set and get the error on TextInputLayout
     * */
    var error: String
        get() = textInputLayout.error.toString()
        set(value) {
            textInputLayout.error = value
        }

    /**
     * Add a listener for text change
     * */
    fun setOnTextChangeListener(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        this.onTextChangeListener = listener
    }
}
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:hint="Testing" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your Build-Tools version and Android studio version?

Comment: @ParikshitChalke 28.0.2

Comment: What is your android studio version ??

Comment: @ParikshitChalke 3.2, I have everything latest. (each and every dependency)

Comment: your xml doesn't show usage of custom view.

Comment: Is only above layout is not being rendered? or other all your layouts are also not get rendered.

Comment: @ParikshitChalke Only the layout is not getting rendered. All other views are visible.

In the Kotlin file when I just inflate the view, the layout shows up, but when I add any extra line of code, like finding the TextInputLayout, TextInputEditText the layout won't render.

Comment: Strange !!!!  Have tried 'Invalidate catches & Restart' option

Comment: @ParikshitChalke Tired it, but didn't work.